# WiFi QR Code format for WPA2/WPA3

Tags: wifi-configuration, wpa, qr-code

I'm creating a new QR code for my WiFi guest network and with my new router it supports WPA2/WPA3 Personal (AES).

I've tried multiple iterations of the auto-configuration format (which I can't find official documentation for?), but none works. I use this;

```
WIFI:S:SSID_NAME;H:true;T:WPA2;P:PASSWORD;;
```

And then so far I tried to replace `WPA2` with;

- `WPA2-3`
- `WPA23`
- `WPA2/WPA3`
- `WPA2-WPA3`
- `WPA2-WPA3-AES`
- `WPA3`

All fail to become a valid scannable QR code.

It's probably very simple, but honestly without proper documentation I have no idea what it would want me to insert here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format was originally invented, and documented, by the [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#wi-fi-network-config-android-ios-11) QR decoder. There is no value for WPA3 (or WPA2 for that matter) because the value `T:WPA` means *any* WPA version, not just WPA1 (although ZXing accepts "T:WPA2", it treats it identically to "T:WPA"), and partly because the development of ZXing had already been abandoned by the time WPA3 was published.

Since then, the format has been adopted by Wi-Fi Alliance and is part of the [WPA3 Specification](https://www.wi-fi.org/system/files/WPA3%20Specification%20v3.2.pdf#page=25) (page 25). It always uses `T:WPA` for the "security type" field (indicating any form of password-based authentication), but adds `R:1` for "WPA2/WPA3 transition mode disable" – for devices which understand it. Because of this, it doesn't have an option to outright prevent the use of WPA2 if nothing better is supported. (This might be deliberate.)

Not all QR code scanners support all features of the format – even on a WPA3-capable device, older apps (e.g. those based on ZXing) will not recognize the `R` tag at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I just tested it and works perfectly. I ran a WiFi diagnostic on iOS and it instantly shows it choosing WPA3. Thank you again!

Comment: The link above was not working for me, but I found this one on the alliance site: https://www.wi-fi.org/file/wpa3tm-specification

Relevant information is still on page 24